# Why generic for type parameter cannot be implied here (with two type parameters)?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

I have a generic method defined as

```
void Foo<TIn>(TIn inValue)
{
    //Do something here with inValue
}
```

I can call this method by either way

```
Foo<string>("foo"); or Foo("foo");
```

But if I have a method defined as

```
TOut Bar<TOut,TIn>(TIn inValue)
{
     //assume we return an object type of TOut here
}
```

Why can I no longer be able to call Bar with the implicit TIn like this

```
int result= Bar<int>("");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the fact that there's two type parameters, it's the fact that generic return types are never deduced. C# does not support type inference for return values. Additionally if you specify type parameters explicitly, you must specify all of them. Specifying just some of the parameters and letting type inference figure out the rest is not supported.

As to why specifying only a part of the type parameters isn't supported, it's largely a language design decision. One problem with supporting it I can come up with is this: it would require a change to the syntax, because if you had the following two functions:

```
TOut Foo<TOut, TIn>(TIn arg) { ... }
string Foo<TIn>(TIn arg) { ... }
```

the call

```
string s = Foo<string>("bar")
```

would be ambiguous between the two, and you would need special syntax to specify which one you want. Currently there can be no such ambiguity as the number of type parameters in the method definition and call must match exactly. The people who design C# decided that it's too rare of a use-case to spend the effort adding support for.

If you use both of the type parameters in the function arguments for instance, C# will be able to deduce the types just fine.

Comment: My question is about WHY "Specifying just some of the parameters and letting type inference figure out the rest is not supported."?